# SQLAlchemy upsert Function for MySQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have used the following documentation as a guide and tried to implement an upset mechanism for my Games table. I want to be able to dynamically update all columns of the selected table at a time (without having to specify each column individually). I have tried different approaches, but none have provided a proper SQL query which can be executed. What did I misunderstand respectively what are the errors in the code?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/12/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=on_duplicate_key_update#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4483

```
class Game(CustomBase, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'

    game_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    hall_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(SportPlace.id), nullable=False)

    team_id_home = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Team.team_id))
    team_id_away = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Team.team_id))
    score_home = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    score_away = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

    ...

def put_games(games): # games is a/must be a list of type Game

    insert_stmt = insert(Game).values(games)
    #insert_stmt = insert(Game).values(id=Game.game_id, data=games)
    
    on_upset_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(**games)

    print(on_upset_stmt)
    ...
```

I regularly load original data from an external API (incl. ID) and want to update my database with it, i.e. update the existing entries (with the same ID) with the new data and add missing ones without completely reloading the database.

**Updates**
The actual code results in

> TypeError: on_duplicate_key_update() argument after ** must be a
> mapping, not list

With the commented line #insert_statement... instead of first insert_stmt is the error message

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: data

Comment: Can you add more details about what is going wrong? Any errors that you get.

Comment: @rfkortekaas sure, the actual code results in TypeError: on_duplicate_key_update() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list 

and with the commented line #insert_statement...: sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: data

Comment: Can you print the contents of `games` and `type(games)`?

Comment: The first error looks pretty clear but I don't want to set every class field individually for a desired mapping. It should be generic based on the class as much as possible

Comment: Please add the requested, maybe you need to unpack with 1 `*`, but without the contents and type I cannot guess what the solution can be!

Comment: `print("game in list games")`: game_id': 778, 'date_time': '2021-01-03 12:30:00', 'hall_id': 5, 'team_id_home': 15, 'team_id_away': 17, 'score_home': 3, 'score_away': 1}  (is only one entry in list actually)

`print(type(games))`: <class 'list'>

Comment: `print(type("game in list games"))`: <class 'Game'>

Comment: Can you try to use `data=insert_stmt.inserted.data` instead of `**games`?

Comment: new `on_upset_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(data=insert_stmt.inserted.data)` results in error message in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(key) AttributeError: data

Comment: @rfkortekaas more ideas?